# What alternatives exists to Democracy Index?

Tags: democracy

I am aware of the [Democracy Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index).

What it lacks that I am interested in is more information about what type of political system each country has, and the connection to its democratic level. I would, for instance, like to have the ranking include a categorization of the “type of democracy”. Does such a categorization exist?

Comment: "Does such a ranking exist?" - I think the better question is, "Does such a categorization exist?".

Comment: Wikipedia categorizes the governments of each country but I don't know if there is a page organizing them.  It's listed in the infobox of each country.  For example, the United States is listed as a Federal presidential constitutional republic.

Comment: @Brythan - That is not an authoritative way of categorizing governments.  For example, "Presidential" is not a discrete category and there is a lot of debate about what "presidential" republics are.  Of course "republic" is a difficult term to pin down too - is it a kind of democracy? Is it different than a democracy? Which leads to the problem of what a democracy is...

Comment: The Wold Almanac and CIA Factbook each have a capsule summary of the form of government and history of every government in the world.